# How do I install WFDS (Wildfire Dynamic Simulator) when openmpi library "is not loaded"?

Tags: nist

I've been trying to install WFDS for a few days and no matter what I try I keep getting this error:

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/openmpi-2.0.1/lib/libmpi_usempif08.20.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/wfds
Reason: image not found

I've tried adding the path variables to my nano shell but that has not worked either.
The WFDS executable is located within my bin folder along with the FDS executable. I should note theta FDS works perfectly fine. Any tips are appreciated.